# Is it good to use Excel interop in an MVC.net application to Expose Excel calculations to web

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web application developed with MVC.net. In this application i create a simple user interface to represent some cells of an excel file. When user change values of the UI it has to get reflected in the Excel file and needs to do some calculations and return results to the UI. I was using Excel interop for this solution and i don't need to save it back to the Excel.

Is this a fine solution or is it not a recommended one. If there are any other solutions please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.